# Formatting Google Places API GeoJSON and Import to QGIS?

Tags: geojson, qgis-2, google-maps-api, syntax

I'm trying to export JSON or XML data to my desktop and import it to QGIS.

This is the URL I'm using but it appears to be incorrectly formatted:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=51.503186,-0.126446&radius=9000&keywords=exchange&types=bank&key=AIzaSyDyGA1g71hnK85zIMZ7CVp0CKoiRfG_Fpk

My goal is to query the Google API and receive a JSON or XML file that I can then load into QGIS/ArcGIS... etc. as a feature dataset. The JSON text that is received with the API query has incorrect syntax and this fails to load, please advise?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  Could you please add a clearly defined question to the body of the question?

Comment: hey aaron is that enough information

Comment: Can you please provide an example response, I don't have an API key to test with.

Comment: that should allow the call now, also im testing my edited syntax with http://geojson.io/#map=2/20.0/0.0 but not having any luck except with the page test data

Comment: Be careful to read the [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) to ensure that you're allowed to do this. Section 10 mentions _No Access to Maps API(s) except through the Service_ and _No Reverse Engineering_. Generally Google doesn't allow you to use their data on a non-Google map

Comment: yes im aware of this, im not a coder, i just want to make seperate querries and use the data at home for some hobby projects, ive been in the gis industry over 8 years now so im aware of the restrictions :)

Comment: Did you ever get this working?